# Getting event.key as undefined intermittently on "keydown" event, with Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the code below in an angular custom directive code to know the keys pressed. It works fine however event.key starts giving undefined intermittently. If i am clearing the cache and trying it again, it starts working again. What could be the possible issue ?

```
<input type="text" input-styler="" class="form-control" id="input-phrase" ng-model="home.inputPhrase" autocomplete="off">

angular
.module('myApp')
.directive('inputStyler', inputStyler);

function inputStyler() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link
    };
    function link(scope, element, attrs){
        element.bind("keydown", function (event) {
            console.log(event.key);
            if((!event.ctrlKey) && (event.key !== " ") && (event.key.length == 1)){
                scope.home.inputPhrase += event.key;
            }

        });


        element.on("cut copy paste", function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    };
    return directive;
}
```

Comment: To which html element(s) are you binding the directive?

Comment: Try using an `ng-click` attribute and see if that resolves itself.

Comment: I am binding it on input element with type text.

Comment: @LukeP.Issac Can you show us the code for that as well? A plunk/fiddle would be even better

Comment: @NexusDuck Have updated the code above with markup and complete custom directive in progress.

Comment: @LukeP.Issac I've constructed a minimal [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wLn54m0p/), but I'm not getting any `undefined` logs

Comment: It comes intermittently. It is reported that often reloading the page after clearing the cache, it works fine.

Comment: I have a doubt that after every update of chrome we need to clear the cache or hard reload the page. Not able to figure out the root cause.